# How to make this hamburger drawer menu slide to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

For this [codepen](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/uIemr), if I make the below modifications (denoted with comments by the word 'modify'), the only thing that happens is the hamburger icon moves to the right and slides from the right (which I want).

But I'd like the menu content to slide out from the right as well.  What am I missing?

```
label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px; top: 15px;  /* modify from left: 15px to right: 15px*/
  z-index: 2;

  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

**CSS Transition effect:**

```
/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
  transition: right 0.2s;  /* modify left with right keyword */
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  right: 215px; /* modify from left to right: 215px */
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  right: 200px; /* modify from left to right: 200px */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

EDIT: "that happens is the hamburger icon moves to the right and slides from the right" - By this I meant the hamburger icon is positioned on the right hand side and when I click it, it slides in a leftward direction from the right.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? One note: The menu content is not sliding from left, its static, the navigation is what is showing up from left which makes you think that the content is sliding.

Comment: I need to have it slide from the right to satisfy design requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Position the `.navigation` menu off-screen using a negative `right` value, and set `right:0;` when the menu is checked.

(like lmgonzalves suggests, move the `.navigation` HTML to after the menu checkbox, to allow use of the `~` sibling selector when your menu is checked)

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nqydvp

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I believe you want. Next time i suggest setting opacity of the main frame to .8 or so. Doing this allows you to see the nav bar and fiddle with it accordingly.

I also suggest using developer tools such as chromes inspect element and then modifying the CSS through their responsive manipulation system for quick debugging.

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvMRZO)

```
    .navigation {
  /* critical sizing and position styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 85%;
  z-index: 0;

  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  list-style: none;
  background: #111;
}
```

...

```
label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px; top: 15px;
  z-index: 2;

  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

...

```
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
  transition: left 0.2s;
}
```

...

```
.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  right: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: -200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives a rough idea.  The menu text is hiding behind the window.

Comment: Hmmmm, it displays fine on this end in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is put the `.navigation` menu after the `input` and `label`, like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>

<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then in CSS do something like this:

```
.navigation {
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.2s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .navigation {
  left: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/e49ejy9h/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit unclear on how your solution is different from the original code pen.  The menu icon should be on the right side and a menu should slide out from the right.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, but in your question you said that you want `menu slide TO the right` not `FROM the right`. I got a little confused ;)

Comment: Ok, I made a little edit to the question and upvoted your answer.  Appreciate the help.